# Creating xml using DOM in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to create a an XML with multiple elements.  Below is the code i am trying.

```
        Element root = doc.createElement("root");
        doc.appendChild(root);

            Element member = doc.createElement("member");
            root.appendChild(member);
            Element name = doc.createElement("name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("xxx"));
            member.appendChild(name);
            Element phone = doc.createElement("phone");
            phone.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("vvvv"));
            member.appendChild(phone);

            Element sss = doc.createElement("somethingNew");
            root.appendChild(sss);
            Element nnn = doc.createElement("name1");
            nnn.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("AAA"));
            sss.appendChild(nnn);
            Element ppp = doc.createElement("phoneEx");
            ppp.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("cc"));
            sss.appendChild(ppp);
```

And the output i am getting is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <member>
     <name>xxx</name>
     <phone>vvvv</phone>
     <name>xxx</name>
     <phone>vvvv</phone>
 </member>
 <somethingNew/>
</root>
```

But i am expecting somthing like Below, Please help me where i am going wriong

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <root>
  <member>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <phone>vvvv</phone>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <phone>vvvv</phone>
 </member>
<somethingNew>
    <name1>DDD</name1>
    <phoneEx>CC</phoneEx>
</somethingNew>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind i could able to find the solution, I am appending to the first element all the time, That was the issue.Corrected my code